# Swift : Trouble Exporting Database

Tags: swift, sqlite, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to Export my Database.
I've tried by Email and by sharing it.

The thing is that I want to export the current state of the dataBase (with all the information in it).

I've tried this code :

```
func exportDatabase(){
    var url:String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).last! as String
    url = url + "/WalletDatabase.sqlite"

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: url) {
        sendMail(sUrl: url)
    }else{
        print("error")
    }
}

func sendMail(sUrl:String){
    if( MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() ) {
        print("Can send email.")

        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposer.setToRecipients(["***@gmail.com"])
        mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self

        //Set the subject and message of the email
        mailComposer.setSubject("Lorem Ipsum")
        mailComposer.setMessageBody("Lorem Ipsum.", isHTML: false)

        if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: sUrl) {
            print("File data loaded.")
            mailComposer.addAttachmentData(fileData as Data, mimeType: "application/x-sqlite3", fileName: "WalletDatabase")
        }
        let fileData = fileManager.contents(atPath: sUrl)             
    } else {
        print("error")
    }
```

But :

- The file send doesn't have any type
- The database is empty, only the table and col remain

Could you guys give me a little help

Comment: "The file send doesn't have any type": `fileName: "WalletDatabase")` => `fileName: "WalletDatabase.typeYouWant")?

Comment: if you are receiving an email with the correct table and column(s). then it looks like it is sending your file. it's just that your file is empty. add some additional debug code to ensure that this db is actually the one in use in the app, that it has rows etc

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by adding this following code :

```
    static func migrateStoreSwift() -> NSURL
{
    let lApp:AppController = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppController;
    let lCurrentStore:NSPersistentStore = lApp.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.last!
    let lNewDataBase = "Database.sqlite"
    let lNewStoreURL:NSURL = lApp.applicationDocumentsDirectory()?.appendingPathComponent(lNewDataBase) as! NSURL
    try! lApp.persistentStoreCoordinator.migratePersistentStore(lCurrentStore, to: lNewStoreURL as URL, options: nil, withType: NSSQLiteStoreType)
    return lNewStoreURL
}
```

This code create a copy of the current version of the database.